# Background Position Variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Hello im trying to make my background animate up and down using the .animate() and .hover() method in jQuery. In my DOM i have a div with id="#menu" that contains an UL list with each having a background at different x positions but the same y position. My dilema is for some reason my variable is not working. its coming back as error "cannot read property '1' of null value. Which means it doesnt exist?

**Here is my code:**

```
$("#menu li").hover(
 function () {
 var xPos = $(this).css('background-position-x')  
 $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "("+ xPos + "0px)"}, 500); 

         }
 , 
 function () {
   var xPos = $(this).css('background-position-x')  
 $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: xPos + "35px"}, 500); 

             }
);
```

Comment: Do you have a background position set initially in your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem is with the variable, when i check alert(typeof xPos) it returns as undefined. I need to convert this answer to an integer value only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this might be help you.

Actually Default value: 0% 0% In Css Background Property.

```
$("#menu li").hover(
 function () {
 var xPos = $(this).css('background-position')  
 $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "("+ xPos + "0px)"}, 500); 

         }
 , 
 function () {
   var xPos = $(this).css('background-position')  
 $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: xPos + "35px"}, 500); 

             }
);
```

Comment: nope that doesn't  work, the bug here is when i put the addition operator i get an error, the xPos value is returning as "0px" just fine but its not combining the x and y values together. If i replace xPos with for example "20px" +"0px" it still gives me the cannot read property '1' of null value"